# ZFS requested features not enabled

Tags: zfs

I am running a TrueNAS (formerly FreeNAS) based server for about six years now. It is currently running TrueNAS 13.0-U6.1. There is a "boot pool" and a "data pool", both installed with the NAS in 2017 and "upgraded" with it from then on.

Recently I noticed that `zpool status` claims that "some requested features" are not enabled for both pools. Here is the relevant excerpt from the command's output:

```
  pool: data-pool
 state: ONLINE
status: Some supported and requested features are not enabled on the pool.
        The pool can still be used, but some features are unavailable.
action: Enable all features using 'zpool upgrade'. Once this is done,
        the pool may no longer be accessible by software that does not support
        the features. See zpool-features(7) for details.
```

I do (more or less) understand the "some *supported* features are not enabled" part, *but what are **requested** features*? My guess is that *requested* features are features that are (were) enabled on the pool once but are not any longer. Only, that seems somewhat unlikely, because the pool was always running on the same machine; I do not recall to ever have enabled and then disabled features again...

My **main question** now is: (how) can I list *requested* (and if possible "but not enabled") features? Is there a command for this? I think I would likely enable the "requested but not enabled" features, if I knew which ones these are...
There seems to be terribly little information about requested features in the documentation and the Internet in general.

The secondary question being what requested features are, if someone happens to know?

Any hint would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: As this question got downvoted, it seems that something is missing or unclear? I am happy to improve/update the question but unfortunately I currently don't understand what's missing.

Answer (score 0):

This indicates that the zfs pool was created with an older version of zfs than the current one.  I don't think "requested features" means anything special.

You can get a list of what those features are with `zpool upgrade` and then you can look up each listed feature.

The `zpool upgrade -a` command will start the upgrade background job to bring the pool format to the current version.  When that is complete, all the listed features will be available.  Some require additional actions to take advantage, some are immediately effective.

What features are added depends on what version your pool is currently using, and what the new version will be.  You can see a list of all features in the zpool-features man page.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you suggest to handle this exactly like the "requested" was not present in the notification? "Some supported features are not enabled..."? I am curious why the "requested" is mentioned/output then.